# Nodejs express try-catch vs then catch

Tags: node.js, express, async-await, try-catch

Whats better: using await and try and catch or using .then and .catch?

Hi guys,

which of the two methos are better?

```
 app.post("/signup", (req, res) => {
    var user = new User(req.body)

      user.save().then(result => {
        res.status(200).send("success")
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
        res.send(error)
    })


});

app.post("/signupasync", async (req, res) => {

    try {
        var user = new User(req.body)
        await user.save()
        res.status(200).send("success")
   } catch (error) {
       console.log(error)
       res.send(error)
   }
```

Comment: `async/await` syntax offers a linear flow of code, and I find it easier to read. But keep in mind it's not all or nothing. You can use both where it make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Async/await` is actually just a `syntax sugar` built on top of `promises`. It cannot be used with plain `callbacks` or `node callbacks`.

It is just like `promises`, `non blocking`, but makes `asynchronous` code look and behave a little more like `synchronous` code. This is what makes it powerful, thats where all its power lies.

You won't have too many indentations if you go with `async/await`. All your code will be linear and more readable.

Anything †hat can be achieved with `promise (.then().catch(0))` can be achieved with `async/await.`

Any `async` function returns a `promise` implicitly, and the resolved value of the promise will be whatever you return from the function. Even if you return a simple value and not a `promise`, it wraps it in a `promise` before returning.